# Is it possible to declare a type at function scope in F#?

Tags: f#, functional-programming

Let's say I have a function which does something pretty complicated and it is implemented with the help of subfunctions. To make things easier, instead of tuples I would like to use some intermediate structures which are private to the implementation of this function.

I don't want the declaration of these structures to leak outside. So I want something like this:

```
let someComplexFun p =
    type SomeRecord      = {i:int; x:int; y:int;}
    type SomeOtherRecord = {...}

    let innerFunctionA (x:SomeRecord) = ...
    let innerFunctionB (x:SomeOtherRecord) = ...

    ...
```

I tried it but of course the compiler doesn't let me do this. I looked at the documentation and I can't see anywhere quickly that the types must be declared at the module level.

In LISP for example, it seems that it's all entirely legal, e.g.:

```
(defun foo (when)
    (declare (type (member :now :later) when)) ; Type declaration is illustrative and in this case optional.
    (ecase when
        (:now (something))
        (:later (something-else))))
```

So, am I missing something? Is this possible if F# at all?

Comment: maybe functions are first-class but classes are not ;) ... no it's really strange - why not compile such a thing into a annonymous class? But the solution is easy enough as Komrade P. wrote. I think if your function is so long that you need to give inner types then maybe you should think about some refactoring anyway

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To verify that this is not allowed according to the specification, take a look at the grammar of F# expressions in the specification: [Section 6: Expressions](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597435). It lists various constructs that can be used in place of `expr` and none of them is a type declaration `type-defn` (described in [Section 8: Type Declarations](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597534)).

The (simplified) syntax for function declarations is `let ident args = expr`, so the body has to be an expression (and you cannot declare types inside expressions).

Answer (score 2):

Types can only be declared at module or namespace scope in F#.

(You can use access modifiers like `internal` or signature files to hide types from other components.)

Comment: Where exactly in the documentation does it say so? I couldn't find it. Link please?

Comment: If you want "proof", you can look at the language specifications. Also, if you create a module only for these functions, it would be better to mark the types as private and not as internal. Private means only in that specific module, internal means only in that specific "project" (or assembly).

Answer (score 0):

What Brian said.

heres a link to some more information http://www.ctocorner.com/fsharp/book/ch17.aspx